# Error creating ForwardingRule, A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, load-balancing

I'm trying to create a regional load balancer using terrafrom, but i'am unable to create the forwarding rules and regional http(s) proxies.

```
resource "google_compute_region_ssl_certificate" "ssl-crt" {
  project = "proyecto-pegachucho"
  name_prefix = "my-certificate-"
  region = var.lb_region
  private_key = file("lb_http/certificate/privateKey.key")
  certificate = file("lb_http/certificate/certificate.crt")

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTP" {
  name                  = var.lb_front_name
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  port_range            = var.lb_front_port_range
  target                = google_compute_region_target_http_proxy.lb-proxy-http.self_link
  region                = var.lb_region
  network               = var.lb_network
  subnetwork            = var.lb_subnetwork
  ip_address            = "10.10.30.5"
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTPS" {
  name                  = "lb-https-front"
  port_range            = "443"
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  ip_address            = "10.10.30.6"
  target                = google_compute_region_target_https_proxy.lb-proxy-https.self_link
  region                = var.lb_region
  network               = var.lb_network
  subnetwork            = var.lb_subnetwork
}


resource "google_compute_region_target_http_proxy" "lb-proxy-http" {
  name    = var.lb_proxy_name
  region  = var.lb_region
  project = "proyecto-pegachucho"
  url_map = google_compute_region_url_map.lb_url_map.self_link
}

resource "google_compute_region_target_https_proxy" "lb-proxy-https" {
  name             = "test-proxy"
  region           = var.lb_region
  project = "proyecto-pegachucho"
  url_map          = google_compute_region_url_map.lb_url_map.self_link
  ssl_certificates = [google_compute_region_ssl_certificate.ssl-crt.id]
}


resource "google_compute_region_url_map" "lb_url_map" {
  name            = var.url_map_name
  region          = var.lb_region
  default_service = google_compute_region_backend_service.lb-backend.self_link
}


resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "lb-backend" {
  name                  = var.lb_backend_name
  region                = var.lb_region
  project = "proyecto-pegachucho"
  load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL_MANAGED"
  port_name             = var.lb_backend_port_name
  protocol              = var.lb_backend_protocol
  timeout_sec           = var.lb_backend_timeout
  health_checks         = [var.healthcheck_output]
  locality_lb_policy    = "ROUND_ROBIN"

  backend {
    group = var.ig_id
    balancing_mode = "UTILIZATION"
    capacity_scaler = 1.0
  }
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error: Error creating ForwardingRule: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/targetHttpProxies/lb-proxy'. A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule., invalid

  on lb_http\lb_http.tf line 13, in resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTP":
  13: resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTP" {



Error: Error creating ForwardingRule: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/targetHttpsProxies/test-proxy'. A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule., invalid

  on lb_http\lb_http.tf line 24, in resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTPS":
  24: resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb-front-HTTPS" {
```

I tried using google beta provider but it seems that i don´t have permissions while i have owner permissions on my terraform service account.

```
Error: Error creating RegionSslCertificate: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.regionSslCertificates.create' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/sslCertificates/my-certificate-20210628014206664300000001', forbidden

  on lb_http\lb_http.tf line 1, in resource "google_compute_region_ssl_certificate" "ssl-crt":
   1: resource "google_compute_region_ssl_certificate" "ssl-crt" {



Error: Error creating RegionBackendService: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.regionBackendServices.create' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/backendServices/lb-backend'      
More details:
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.regionBackendServices.create' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/backendServices/lb-backend'
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.healthChecks.useReadOnly' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/global/healthChecks/hsbc-healthcheck-dev'
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.instanceGroups.use' permission for 'projects/proyecto-pegachucho/zones/us-central1-b/instanceGroups/tomcats-ig'


  on lb_http\lb_http.tf line 59, in resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "lb-backend":        
  59: resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "lb-backend" {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create a proxy-only subnet before you create forwarding rules for your internal HTTP(S) load balancers. Each region of a virtual private network (VPC) in which you use internal HTTP(S) load balancers must have a proxy-only subnet.

The error message displayed describes it in the last sentence:

`Error creating ForwardingRule: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/proyecto-pegachucho/regions/us-central1/targetHttpProxies/lb-proxy'.` **`A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule.`**

To solve this you can either manually [create](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/proxy-only-subnets#proxy_only_subnet_create) said proxy-only subnet through the [gcloud compute networks subnets create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/subnets/create) command or use the terraform variant through [google_compute_subnetwork](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_subnetwork) where all the same fields are available, you can use the documentation in [create](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/proxy-only-subnets#proxy_only_subnet_create) as a guide and then trespass it all over to terraform.

**Note that this must be done before creating the forwarding rules for your internal HTTP(S) LB**

I hope the provided solution can be of help!

Comment: Thanks for your response, i fixed it using a diferent provider, google-beta instead google. I tried to answer to my question but somehow I'm "banned" to answering questions.